# Qt Creator does not run

Tags: linux-mint, qt

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1. Downloaded Qt, installed it fine. When I run it, I get the error: `/home/eddie/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf(129): Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.`

I'm a COMPLETE noob and I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you installed Qt. But you should try to use the software manager from your distribution.

Here is a guide on how you can install and use Qt Creator in Linux Mint:

https://mintguide.org/tools/422-qt-creator-excellent-integrated-development-environment.html

Comment: The software manager has version 3.5.1. I'd like something a little more up-to-date if possible. But I tried it anyway - same result. I also followed the procedure in your link carefully. Different error this time - 'no valid kits found'. I've googled 'til I'm blue in the face, but I can not get it to run.

Comment: "No valid kits" means you don't have a valid combination of a compiler and qt-libraries installed. Qt Creator is "just" the integrated development environment (IDE) you need to have [a compiler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689722/how-to-install-a-c-c-compiler-in-ubuntu-14-04lts) installed. Additionally you need the qt-libraries. [This is a hint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184855/why-wont-qt-sdk-install) on how to install one.